# Is rest api used only for crud operations

Tags: rest, api

I am beginner at web development and faced some confusion in REST API, that is, I understood that REST API is perfectly suited to do CRUD operations in a faster way since server returns data instead of markup I hope I am correct. So, the question is Is REST API used purely to perform CRUD operations faster since data is exchanged faster? Please guys help or tell me what is wrong with my question

Comment: No, REST is about how your API represents data and interactions with that data as objects...CRUD is well suited to a REST api, but you can think about just about anything as an entity. Your question is a yes or no question, though, so it's not terribly answerable. Can you rephrase so it's answerable in a bit more depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am beginner at web development and faced some confusion in REST API

That is not your fault; the web has a lot more writing about REST than it has understanding about REST.

> Is rest api used only for crud operations?

No - but the facade *looks* like we're just doing generic crud operations, and from that we get a lot of power and re-usability.

Jim Webber's [2011 summary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) is the best I know of.  It looks like all we are doing is CRUD operations on documents, but interesting business activities can occur as a *side effect* of the changes to the documents.

A REST API is a disguise that our domain model wears so that it looks like a dumb document store with standardized semantics.

> we simply take resource from a database which is in server with GET and can perform actions on the resource like DELETE and UPDATE in a FAST WAY since we deal with data instead of HTML markup. Am I right?

No, I wouldn't write it that way at all.  The World Wide Web, HTML and all, *is* REST (to first order).  Resources can have more than one representation; REST is designed so that HTML capable clients can ask for HTML, and JSON capable clients can ask for JSON, and clients that understand both can negotiate with the server to choose.

If you have it in mind that REST, or REST APIs, means JSON, then you are on the wrong track.

Comment: hey dude, thank you for your answer, so, basically with REST API, we simply take resource from a database which is in server with GET and can perform actions on the resource like DELETE and UPDATE in a FAST WAY since we deal with data instead of HTML markup. Am I right?

Comment: please I really need your help

Comment: if you did not understand my question please let me know